# Relative Path Links/Hyperlinks in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, file-path

Has anyone figured out how to use hyperlinks/relative links in ArcGIS Pro? This is what my links look like in ArcMap. The hyperlink lightning bolts are there.

[image]

Here is what it looks like in ArcGISPro:

[image]

The link is not working in ArcGIS Pro.  Is there something that needs to be turned on?  Is ESRI aware of this issue and are they addressing it?  Are there any work arounds?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I'm in ArcPro v 2.9.5; including your version may help. This discussion forum is kind of winding but may help: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/how-can-i-quot-store-relative-pathnames-quot-in/td-p/453649  Ultimately I haven't found a working solution yet though.